# SQL join two table together where value is between two rows and you get first row

Tags: sql, oracle

TABLE LSF

```
ID  LID     FV      TYPE            
28  22      1       INCREMENTAL     
29  22      5       FULL
```

TABLE LFG

```
ID  WHAT    WHERE   TYPE
22  V1      4444    WHITE
```

ID is Primary KEY and is a SEQUENCE on both tables.

now I want to connect these two tables

```
SELECT LFG.* FROM LSF sf, LFG fg WHERE sf.LID = fg.ID AND ...
```

and I want to get first row from LSF table. But is empty.

If sf.FV in SELECT statement is 1, 2, 3 or 4 returns first row, if is 5 or more return row 2 of table LSF. How to write select like this?

EDIT:

What I want?

In table LSF FV means from when is something INCREMENTAL or FULL. If I have version 1 is INCREMENTAl, the same for version 2 or 3 or 4. But if I have version 5 or more is FULL.

Now my problem is that I am not storing each version in table I just say from here is INCREMENTAL and from here is FULL. My problem is how to write a select statement for that when I have version 3 how to know that this is FROM 1 to 5 and that means INCREMENTAL.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: why? it has sense. I don't know how to write select statement for that

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more explanation as to what it is your trying to do as it's not 100% clear!?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: There are still some things unclear: Why does your table LFG contain 4 columns, but you provide 10 values? Where is the connection between LFG and LFS (LFG doesn't contain any version /FV column) ?

Comment: Also, please use your real column names - DATE and WHERE are reserved words and won't work.

Comment: What do you mean `and somehow include sf.FV=3`?

Comment: @Frank i remove unnecessarry fields. LID from table LSF is foreign key of ID from table LFG. That is all. No other connections

Comment: I am working with oracle analytic function but i don't know if approach is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FG.* FROM LSF sf, LFG fg WHERE sf.LID = fg.ID AND sf.fv = (SELECT MAX(fv) FROM LSF WHERE fv<=3)
```

Comment: you are a genius Nenad :D I think this is it. Simple solution but I was trying with analytic oracle functions :S

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot and see if you get what your looking for. It should return the most recent version match the LID that has either 1,2,3 or 4 set for FV.

```
SELECT LFG.* 
FROM LSF sf, LFG fg 
WHERE sf.LID = fg.ID 
AND sf.FV >= 1 
AND sf.FV < 5
ORDER BY sf.FV DESC;
```

Comment: thank you but sf.FV is not just 1 and 5. Can be any numbers. This just means from where to where is something INC or FULL. Solution must work for all versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
  b.*, a.* 
FROM 
  LSF ls,
  LFG b, 
  (SELECT 
     lid, 
     min(ID) as id 
  FROM 
     LSF 
  GROUP BY 
     lid) a
WHERE 
  a.lid = b.id AND a.id = ls.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
SELECT LFG.* 
FROM LSF sf, LFG fg 
WHERE sf.LID = fg.ID 
AND sf.Type='INCREMENTAL'
ORDER BY sf.Type DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

`...and somehow include sf.FV=3`

```
  SELECT LFG.* FROM LSF sf, LFG fg WHERE sf.LID = fg.ID AND ...
   and I want to get first row from LSF table. But is empty.
```

Select the columns you want *individually* from the tables involved in the join.

```
         select t1.someDate, t1.description, t2.blahblah, t2.someOtherColumn
         from 
         foo as T1
         inner join widget as T2
         on T1.orange = T2.banana
```